# Restructuring JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I have a json file with multiple data stored as follows:

```
{"name": ["Adelphi University"], "supp": ["Yes: E, WS"], "ed": ["\u00a0"], "online": ["$40"], "ea": ["12/1"], "mid": ["No"], "rd": ["Rolling"], "recs": ["Yes: CR"], "mail": ["$40"], "schoolr": ["Yes"]}
```

This line is supposed to represent a university (hence the name) and the variables following "name", i.e. "supp", "online" etc., are attributes of that school. How would I restructure this data to have the "name" variable define the data and the other variables be cildren of the "name" parent. My data should look like this:

```
{
  "schools": {
    "Adelphi University": {
      "supp": "Yes: E, WS",
      "ed": "\u00a0",
      "online": "$40",
      "ea": "12/1", 
      "mid": "No", 
      "rd": "Rolling", 
      "recs": "Yes: CR", 
      "mail": "$40", 
      "schoolr": "Yes",    
    },
    "Dartmouth College": { ... },
    "Harvard University": { ... }
  }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Show your code; what have you tried so far?

Comment: By the way, I disagree with the "close as too broad" vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and test for `name`, then build an object with the name and assign a temp object. Otherwise assing the values.

```js
var array = [{ "name": ["Adelphi University"], "supp": ["Yes: E, WS"], "ed": ["\u00a0"], "online": ["$40"], "ea": ["12/1"], "mid": ["No"], "rd": ["Rolling"], "recs": ["Yes: CR"], "mail": ["$40"], "schoolr": ["Yes"] }, { "name": ["Dartmouth College"], "supp": ["Yes: E, WS"], "ed": ["\u00a0"], "online": ["$40"], "ea": ["12/1"], "mid": ["No"], "rd": ["Rolling"], "recs": ["Yes: CR"], "mail": ["$40"], "schoolr": ["Yes"] }],
    schools = {},
    result = { schools: schools };

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var temp = {};
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        if (k === 'name') {
            schools[a[k][0]] = temp;
            return;
        }
        temp[k] = a[k][0];
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How would I keep the " " quotations around the variable names and variables? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by keeping the quotes around?

Comment: For the what I need it for, the JSON data needs the quotes -- otherwise it won't run. I have over 600 pieces of data and adding them by hand would be tedious.

Comment: can you add a small example? or are you talking about a [JSON](http://json.org/) string

Comment: Yep, I'm talking about a JSON string. Something like this { schools:
   `{ "Adelphi University":
      { "supp": "Yes: E, WS",
        "ed": " ",
        "online": "$40",
        "ea": "12/1",
        "mid": "No",
        "rd": "Rolling",
        "recs": "Yes: CR",
        "mail": "$40",
        "schoolr": "Yes" }`

Comment: something like above now?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the object you showed as your starting point is one record in an array of things that look the same, you could do something like this:

```
var schoolArray = [/** your current json structure **/];
var schools = {};

schoolArray.forEach(function(item) { 
  //probably want to test for existence here, just in case
  var name = item.name[0];
  schools[name] = {};
  delete item.name;
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) { 
    // again, testing for existence on the right hand side woudl be a good idea. 
    schools[name][key] = item[key][0];
  });
});

console.log({ schools : schools });  // should be the structure you asked for.
```

Comment: The code works but it removes the " " quotation marks from the variable names and variables. Is there any way to keep them?

Comment: This gives  you a javascript object.  If you want JSON again, just JSON.stringify the object.